# Tool for capturing screenshots in TFS2010 Web Access

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, custom-controls, tfs-web-access

I need a tool to capture and attach screenshots in TFS team web access. Instead of having some thrid party tool that captures and saves images on disk and then you have to attach that image to a bug like bugshooting. I want something integrated within TFS.

Comment: [Linked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9584977/147211)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hofman said, you can do it with VS 11 beta, so you can use MS Paint or even SnagIt, for how to do it just see the following link:

http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/new-enhancement-in-mtm-11-preview/

Answer (score 2):

In VS11 it is possible to copy and paste your screen shots in the description field of the work item. You can check out the [VS11 Beta version](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us) yourself.

Comment: In Web Access you need to add it from a disk.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing integrated in VS, but there are a couple of easy options:

- use the standard Windows screenshot function.  Alt-PrtScrn will capture the current window, and then you can paste into your work item's Attachments pane.  It'll create a generic filename and attach as a PNG.
- if you're using Win7, try the "Snipping tool" (just press Start and type "snip" to find it).  That will capture a specified area and can then copy it to the clipboard or save to a file.  If you copy & paste you still have the problem of generic filenames, though, so personally I still tend to save it myself.

Comment: Tried using snipping tool but I can copy the screenshot but coulndt able to paste it in bug/issue in TFS2010. Any idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Make sure you're pasting into the Attachments tab - it only works there.  Not sure what else I could suggest - the attachments tab seems to accept pastes of a number of different data types (text, image, etc).

Comment: @DanPuzey He's asking about Team Web Access. Thanks for the paste tip though :)

Comment: I can do this in Team Explorer but cant do the copy paste if using MS Team Web Access. as few of staff needs to acess via web not from VS.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a solution through web access except to save the file and then attach it.  Web access isn't as extensible as the VS client, and doesn't support these features by default.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the Capture Custom Control - you can use it to embed a "Capture" button in your work items. It automatically attaches the screenshot to your work item.

Check it out at http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screenshot%20controls&ProjectName=witcustomcontrols

Comment: checked this as well. Its documentation says : (and no, the TFS web client will currently not handle custom controls).

Answer (score 0):

there are a very powerful tool which comes with Windows Server 2008 (Actually I'm not sure if it comes with windows 8 or 7) 
never-mine.., the tool called "Record Steps To Reproduce the Problems" , this tool built for Taking screenshots of doing any thing in your machine step by step... WOW

You just need to  open the start panel and then write "record steps to reproduce a problem". starting record, and make you job that you want, then when you finish stop recording and save the zip file in your machine.

the zip file will expose a word document contains every single click that you make and every page you've open with some description.