# Any opensource tool like snagit for TFS2010

Tags: bug-tracking, snapshot

I have explored snagit for capturing images and then it has a feature to attach it automatically to TFS2010 new item/bug. Any one know any free tool like this for doing same task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [tool for capturing screenshots in TFS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581475/tool-for-capturing-screenshots-in-tfs2010)

Comment: @EdwardThomson That question was about Web Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [capture control](http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screenshot%20controls&referringTitle=Home) included in the [WIT Custom Controls](http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/).

[image: capture control]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the MS Test Manager tool, when running tests there is a built-in tool to take snapshots (whole screen, or rectangular area, or window).  It automatically attaches them to the resulting test run and bug.

I also know of a free WP7 app that allows you to take a photo and auto-attach it to a TFS WI: http://www.windowsphone.com/nl-NL/apps/18418f3d-4843-4df3-9b2c-e26548da6211?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Free WP7 says it is required to have Windows Phone 7 or higher.? How will it work on PC with Windows 7 enterprise edition.

Comment: WP7 means Windows Phone 7.  It is an app for your phone, not for your PC.